# angular post method variables

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I've gone several answers on this forum as well as checking angular's documentation but for some reason I'm stuck. I'm using angular and nodejs on the backend.

**Attempt 1**

```
    var config = {
        //data: $.param(token.body),
        data: {'message': 'Hello world'},
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    };

   $http.post("/admin/SignInWithCredentials", config)
```

**Attempt 2**

```
$http.post("/admin/SignInWithCredentials", {message: "Hello World"})
```

**Nodejs end I see**

```
console.log(request.query, request.params, request.method);

{} {} 'POST'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) you should be expecting the POST to contain a body.  Try printing out `request.body`.

For reference, [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query) is what is in `request.query`, and [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) is what's in `request.params`.  It would make sense that both of these are empty objects from the examples you've given.

Comment: I'm not using body-parser, req.body returned `undefined`, do I've to use it, shouldn't be accessible out of the box in express?

Comment: It was part of Express 3x, but pulled out for Express 4x.  The reason being they wanted to allow people to customize what they wanted to, without making any assumptions for them.  That said, I've never _not_ used it.  Just drop this line in: `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.  And try printing out `request.body` again.

Comment: Ahh, I've just realized you never said you were using Express.  If you aren't using it, let me know and we can try to figure out another solution.

Comment: I've another problem, after employing body parser, I'm getting my data in a format that I can't use, `{ '{"emailAddress":"email@yahoo.com","password":"pass"}': '' }`

Comment: the value pairs are string itself, while the value is `''` empty, stuck again bro.

Comment: Hmm, that is quite unusable.  Will you open up debugging tools in your browser and check to see if that's how the request is being sent, or if it's something with the bodyParser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77940/discussion-between-brennan-and-user2727195).

Answer (score 1):

You are setting arguments incorrectly... `data` is not part of `config` object

```
$http.post(url, data, [config]);
```

Reference : [$http.post() docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Comment: thanks for clearing up that part, though in my second attempt I tried that, turns out, needed body parser stuff at the server end